# Remix-deployed contract throws the error "We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail"

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I deployed smart contract using the remix online IDE, Whenever I want to perform any of the functions parameters, using etherscan UI interface on the **Goerli Network** I get the error:

> We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail.

[The deployed contract link:](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x6187552c2b938c93efc016a19e8c173870d94744#writeContract)

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

library AddressUpgradeable {

    function isContract(address account) internal view returns (bool) {
        return account.code.length > 0;
    }

    function sendValue(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Address: insufficient balance");

        (bool success, ) = recipient.call{value: amount}("");
        require(success, "Address: unable to send value, recipient may have reverted");
    }

    function functionCall(address target, bytes memory data) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionCall(target, data, "Address: low-level call failed");
    }

    function functionCall(
        address target,
        bytes memory data,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionCallWithValue(target, data, 0, errorMessage);
    }

    function functionCallWithValue(
        address target,
        bytes memory data,
        uint256 value
    ) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionCallWithValue(target, data, value, "Address: low-level call with value failed");
    }


    function functionCallWithValue(
        address target,
        bytes memory data,
        uint256 value,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        require(address(this).balance >= value, "Address: insufficient balance for call");
        require(isContract(target), "Address: call to non-contract");

        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.call{value: value}(data);
        return verifyCallResult(success, returndata, errorMessage);
    }

    function functionStaticCall(address target, bytes memory data) internal view returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionStaticCall(target, data, "Address: low-level static call failed");
    }

    function functionStaticCall(
        address target,
        bytes memory data,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal view returns (bytes memory) {
        require(isContract(target), "Address: static call to non-contract");

        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.staticcall(data);
        return verifyCallResult(success, returndata, errorMessage);
    }

    function verifyCallResult(
        bool success,
        bytes memory returndata,
        string memory errorMessage
    ) internal pure returns (bytes memory) {
        if (success) {
            return returndata;
        } else {
            // Look for revert reason and bubble it up if present
            if (returndata.length > 0) {

                assembly {
                    let returndata_size := mload(returndata)
                    revert(add(32, returndata), returndata_size)
                }
            } else {
                revert(errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}

pragma solidity ^0.8.2;


abstract contract Initializable {

    uint8 private _initialized;

    bool private _initializing;

    event Initialized(uint8 version);


    modifier initializer() {
        bool isTopLevelCall = !_initializing;
        require(
            (isTopLevelCall && _initialized < 1) || (!AddressUpgradeable.isContract(address(this)) && _initialized == 1),
            "Initializable: contract is already initialized"
        );
        _initialized = 1;
        if (isTopLevelCall) {
            _initializing = true;
        }
        _;
        if (isTopLevelCall) {
            _initializing = false;
            emit Initialized(1);
        }
    }

    modifier reinitializer(uint8 version) {
        require(!_initializing && _initialized < version, "Initializable: contract is already initialized");
        _initialized = version;
        _initializing = true;
        _;
        _initializing = false;
        emit Initialized(version);
    }


    modifier onlyInitializing() {
        require(_initializing, "Initializable: contract is not initializing");
        _;
    }

    function _disableInitializers() internal virtual {
        require(!_initializing, "Initializable: contract is initializing");
        if (_initialized < type(uint8).max) {
            _initialized = type(uint8).max;
            emit Initialized(type(uint8).max);
        }
    }
}

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


abstract contract ContextUpgradeable is Initializable {
    function __Context_init() internal onlyInitializing {
    }

    function __Context_init_unchained() internal onlyInitializing {
    }
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        return msg.data;
    }

    uint256[50] private __gap;
}


pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


abstract contract OwnableUpgradeable is Initializable, ContextUpgradeable {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    /**
     * @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
     */
    function __Ownable_init() internal onlyInitializing {
        __Ownable_init_unchained();
    }

    function __Ownable_init_unchained() internal onlyInitializing {
        _transferOwnership(_msgSender());
    }

    /**
     * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        _checkOwner();
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
     */
    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Throws if the sender is not the owner.
     */
    function _checkOwner() internal view virtual {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    }


    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        _transferOwnership(address(0));
    }


    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        _transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }

    function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal virtual {
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }


    uint256[49] private __gap;
}


pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


interface IERC20Upgradeable {
   
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /**
     * @dev Emitted when the allowance of a `spender` for an `owner` is set by
     * a call to {approve}. `value` is the new allowance.
     */
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens in existence.
     */
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    /**
     * @dev Returns the amount of tokens owned by `account`.
     */
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);


    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);


    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);


    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);


    function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) external returns (bool);
}

// File: roman1.sol


pragma solidity ^0.8.2;


interface IUniswapV2Pair {
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);

    function name() external pure returns (string memory);
    function symbol() external pure returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external pure returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);

    function DOMAIN_SEPARATOR() external view returns (bytes32);
    function PERMIT_TYPEHASH() external pure returns (bytes32);
    function nonces(address owner) external view returns (uint);

    function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external;

    event Mint(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1);
    event Burn(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, address indexed to);
    event Swap(
        address indexed sender,
        uint amount0In,
        uint amount1In,
        uint amount0Out,
        uint amount1Out,
        address indexed to
    );
    event Sync(uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1);

    function MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY() external pure returns (uint);
    function factory() external view returns (address);
    function token0() external view returns (address);
    function token1() external view returns (address);
    function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast);
    function price0CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
    function price1CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
    function kLast() external view returns (uint);

    function mint(address to) external returns (uint liquidity);
    function burn(address to) external returns (uint amount0, uint amount1);
    function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external;
    function skim(address to) external;
    function sync() external;

    function initialize(address, address) external;
}

// pragma solidity >=0.6.2;

interface IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);

    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity);
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
    function removeLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function removeLiquidityWithPermit(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermit(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactTokens(
        uint amountOut,
        uint amountInMax,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactETH(uint amountOut, uint amountInMax, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) external pure returns (uint amountB);
    function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountOut);
    function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountIn);
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}



// pragma solidity >=0.6.2;

interface IUniswapV2Router02 is IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountETH);
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountETH);

    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
    function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable;
    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
}



contract Wallet is OwnableUpgradeable {
    IERC20Upgradeable public token;

    
    uint public liquidityBalance = 20 * 10 ** 6 * (10 ** 18); //Should be balance of Wallet contract;

    event Deposit(address indexed account, string id, uint indexed amount);
    event Withdraw(address indexed account, string id, uint indexed amount);
    
    mapping(address => uint256) private walletBalances;
    mapping(address => bool) public shouldBeApps;

    uint tokenPrice = 100000;

    function initialize(address _tokenAddress) external initializer{
        token = IERC20Upgradeable(_tokenAddress);
          __Ownable_init();

    }
    

    function withdraw(address account, string memory id, uint _amount) public {
        require(shouldBeApps[msg.sender], 'Not allowed to access withdrawal');
        require(_amount > 0, 'Withdraw amount should be greated than 0');
        uint currentBalance = walletBalances[account];
        require(currentBalance >= _amount, 'Insufficient wallet balance to withdraw');
        walletBalances[account] = currentBalance-(_amount);

        emit Withdraw(account, id, _amount);
    }

    function depositTokens(address account, string memory id , uint _amount) external{
        require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _amount, "Insufficient balance to transfer");
        require(shouldBeApps[msg.sender], "Not allowed to access deposit");
         token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
        walletBalances[account] += _amount;
        emit Deposit(account, id, _amount);
        }
        
    
    function getApproval(uint amount) public {
        require(shouldBeApps[msg.sender], 'Not allowed to get approval');
        token.approve(msg.sender, amount);
    }

    function walletBalanceOf(address _addr) public view returns(uint){
        return walletBalances[_addr];
    }

    function setTokenAddress(address _addr) public onlyOwner {
        token = IERC20Upgradeable(_addr);
    }
    
    function setApps(address _addr) public onlyOwner {
        shouldBeApps[_addr] = true;
    }
    
    function setLiquidityBalance(uint _value) public onlyOwner {
        liquidityBalance = _value;
    }

    function swapEthToDoxa(string memory id) public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, 'Amount should be greated than 0');
        
        //(,, uint amount) = getTokenPrice(uniswapV2Pair, msg.value);
        uint amount = tokenPrice * msg.value;
        require(liquidityBalance >= amount, 'Insufficient liquidity fund');
        uint currentBalance = walletBalances[msg.sender];
        liquidityBalance = liquidityBalance-(amount);
        walletBalances[msg.sender] = currentBalance+(amount);
        payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value);
    
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, id, amount);
    }

    function getTokenPrice(address pairAddress, uint amount) public view returns(uint, uint, uint) {
        IUniswapV2Pair pair = IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress);
        //IERC20 token1 = IERC20(pair.token1());
        (uint Res0, uint Res1,) = pair.getReserves();

        return(Res0, Res1, (amount*Res0)/Res1); // return amount of token0 needed to buy token1
    }

    function changeTokenPrice(uint _value) public onlyOwner {
        tokenPrice = _value;
    }

    

}
```

The same codes o works on rinkeby, I was just trying to move the contract to Goerli network